# (16.04) How can I permanently disable apport?

Tags: 16.04, services, apport

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/93467/117388), I can disable apport by editing `/etc/default/apport` and setting `enabled=0`.

I have done this:

```
$ cat /etc/default/apport
# set this to 0 to disable apport, or to 1 to enable it
# you can temporarily override this with
# sudo service apport start force_start=1
enabled=0
```

In fact, you can see I actually did this in December 2016:

```
$ stat /etc/default/apport
  File: '/etc/default/apport'
...
Modify: 2016-12-22 09:43:01.688938268 -0500
...
```

Recently I noticed apport was running, so I stopped it and, then rebooted to see if it would come back again

```
$ sudo service apport stop
$ sudo reboot
```

However, on startup, it is indeed active again:

```
$ service apport status
● apport.service - LSB: automatic crash report generation
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apport; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-07-18 11:27:44 EST; 45min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1395 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apport start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 18 11:27:44 foobar systemd[1]: Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
Jul 18 11:27:44 foobar systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
```

You can see I rebooted my machine at 11:27, so apport is being started at startup

```
$ sudo last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-83-generic Tue Jul 18 11:27   still running
```

How can I **permanently** disable apport?

Comment: That is the method and if it is not working you should file a bug report. Either apport is not conformaing to its config file (bug) or the ubuntu documentation on apport needs to be updated.

Comment: Since 16.04 is systemd-based, you should be using `systemctl` to disable/mask unwanted services - see for example [How do I disable unnecessary services without uninstalling them in Ubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/a/726939/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver While that is true, apport should follow it's config file regardless , so IMO this is a bug.

Comment: I updated my answer to add systemd info but I still suggest filing a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The systemd commands would be

Disable

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

If that does not work, you need to mask the service

```
systemctl mask apport.service
```

To reenable

```
systemctl unmask apport.service
sudo systemctl enable apport.service
```

Comment: Using `systemctl disable apport` worked for me, thanks