# Free memory consumed by browser and applications on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, firefox, google-chrome, ram, swap

I have 32 GB ram, that in days get eaten up by using web-browser firefox and other common programming applications. Even my swap get up to 17.9/37.3 GB written. OS Ubuntu 22.04. I have not been able to use google-chrome since update of kernel due to my nvidia GPU card, would have to reverse to my older kernel it seems google-chrome used much less memory.

How does one release or rest memory in real-time via terminal, not having to restart computer ?

Comment: This is not a problem https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ And you really don't need 37 GB of swap. Just a few GBs is enough.

Comment: you may find [this old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1280347/307670) helpgul

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, anyone else can please add thoughts on this if available. I did not get this issue when google-chrome worked before, even though updates often, I cant get google-chrome to work with the new kernel (5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency).